# How to deal with SMS spam?

Tags: spam, sms

Every few weeks, I get an annoying SMS trying to sell me something, or trying to get me to click something, or otherwise spamming me.

I don't think it's a targeted thing- I think my phone number is just out there, or bots are trying random phone numbers. That kind of thing. Sometimes they're clearly from burner e-mail addresses, sometimes not.

In any case, I don't know how to deal with this. Occasionally, I inject a little joy into my day by sending a response text into the void letting the sender know exactly how intensely I hate them, but overwhelmingly I ignore the thing and get on with my day.

Are there any other, more efficacious options available to me?

Additionally, if I were targeted and receiving a deluge of SMS spam, what options would be available to me at that point?

Specifically, I want the sender to suffer in any legally-protected way which is also (hopefully) low-effort from me. Blocking numbers is nice, but it's a hack, not a solution.

Comment: I would assume that the from addresses are mostly fake and you are sending your responses to nowhere.

Comment: @NeilSmithline A person can dream... And I'd assume my carrier's MTA server checks SPF records and does some basic filtering. But I suppose I'm being naive, there.

Comment: @NeilSmithline "I would assume that the from addresses are mostly fake": Not necessarily, receiving a response allows to distinguish live lines and send more spam to them (I suppose it is the same as with emails: list of guaranteed live addresses are more expensively sold, kinda "silver list", the "premium gold" one being if the spammer also managed to establish your profile: sex, age, location, revenue, etc.). That's why it's always a bad idea to answer such message...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something, you can [report the SPAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_spam#Spam_defense).

Depending on your country of residence, you may have different number where you can forward the spam SMS (7726 in the US, 33700 in France, 1909 in India, as mentioned in the linked Wikipedia page). This among other thing is meant to help to detect such messages (still according Wikipedia). You may also have web page to report them (like [this one](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us) handled by the Federal Communication Comission).

In other words, search for "how to report SMS spam" and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

You can report your [mobile phone spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_spam) by forwarding it to US [short code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) **`7726`** (which spells SPAM on a touchtone phone).  You'll get a response asking you for the phone number that sent the spam, the US government will aggregate stats about that spam and possibly pursue the spammer legally, and your SMS provider's filters will be trained against that message as spam.

If you pay per SMS, texting `7726` (and the responses) will not only be free, but it should also automatically revert the charge of the reported message.

Other short codes vary by carrier and/or location:

- AT&T, Sprint, T-Mobile, Verizon, O2, Orange: `7726`
- Three: `37726`
- Vodaphone: `87726`
- France: `33700`
- India: `1909`

[PCWorld wrote](http://www.pcworld.com/article/192469/article.html) in 2010 that France's `33700` had received nearly 500k complaints, resulting in 300 phone numbers being disconnected and "many more" operators being sent cease-and-desist orders.  This data is more useful for training filters than it is for legal responses.

There's a nice writeup by the New York Times (from 2012) on SMS spam called [Fighting Back Against Spam Texts](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/05/technology/personaltech/fighting-back-against-spam-texts.html) that goes into lots of detail, including which providers do what.  See also the official US [FCC's Text spamming](https://www.fcc.gov/document/text-spamming) recommendations and their [official phone complaint form](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39744).  The Internet Patrol has an older [SMS text spam reporting writeup](http://www.theinternetpatrol.com/how-to-stop-sms-text-spam-and-how-to-report-sms-txt-msg-spam/) that talks about contacting customer support and other items.

---

The best anti-spam thing that *you* can do is to deactivate email-originating SMS.  Some vendors let you disable the `1234567890@sms.provider.com` system that is set up for phone number `1234567890` and (optionally) replace it with a custom handle, like `joe1999@sms.provider.com` instead.  Now the spammers have to find you rather than guessing or pulling your phone number from various records.

Legitimate marketers, as well as some of the squirrelly ones, will also accept response messages.  Reply with **`STOP`** back to them and you should be removed.  You may or may not get a response confirming this unsubscribe action (and it may or may not work).

It is also possible (though perhaps unlikely) that joining the US [National Do Not Call registry](https://donotcall.gov/) will also protect you from junk SMS.